# validator function doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

i want to validate the file input field, am new in laravel so i cant figure out what am missing.

**here is my code:**

```
public function postUploadS(){
    $file = array(Input::file('file'));
    $rule = array('file' => 'required'); 
    $validate = Validator::make($file,$rule); 

  if($validate->fails()){
      var_dump($file); exit();
   }
 else{ 
      return View::make('admin.uploadStaff'); } 
     }
```

I i cant get to the **uploadStaff** view even if i choose the file, any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the `$file` array isn't associative, meaning the validator doesn't see any input to compare the `file` rule in `$rule` against.

Change: `$file = array(Input::file('file'));`

to: `$file = array('file' => Input::file('file'));`

...and the validator now knows what input to run against your rule.